# The "almost Hausdorff measure" fails to be subadditive.

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I am working with some "measure" (I think it is not a measure since it is not subadditive) $$m(E)=\inf \left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{diam} F_k:E\subset\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty F_k \right\}.$$ Now I want to prove it is not subadditive. So I consider two disjoint segments $I =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d : x_i=0\text{ if }i\neq 1\text{ and }0\le x_1 \le 1\}$ and $J=I+h$ where $h\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $|h|<\varepsilon$. Now I have to show that $m(I)=m(J)=1$ and $m(I\cup J)\le 1+\varepsilon$. First of all, I can show $m(I)\le 1$ because I can just recover it by I which has diameter $1$. But since we don't have subadditivity, how to show $m(I)\ge 1$?

To show $m(I\cup J)\le 1+\varepsilon$ I am not sure how to proceed. The way I tryed it, is to cover the set $I\cup J$ by the parallelogram generated by $e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $h$ and it's greater diagonal gives the diameter of this set but I think this is not the way to go.

Comment: Is $I+J$ a union or a Minkowski sum here?

Comment: @YuvalPeres, it is a union, thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m(\cdot)$ is subadditive- You are just checking that it is not additive on disjoint closed sets. This is easiest if you take $h=  \epsilon e_2=(0,\epsilon,0,...,0).$

Comment: but taking this $h$ wouldn't $I$ and $J$ overlap?

Comment: Right, corrected.

Comment: Sorry I am late.In the setting you propose, I think $m(I_1\cup I_2)\le m(S)=\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}<2$ if $\epsilon$ is small (here $S$ is the rectangle $S=[0,1]\times[0,\epsilon]$) but how to get $m(I_1\cup I_2)\le 1+\epsilon$ though?

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}<1+\epsilon$ as you can verify by squaring

Comment: Thank you. Was this the same argument you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, this was the argument.